# What is "New transaction is not allowed" error in PHP and SQLSRV driver for?

Tags: php, sql-server, transactions

I'm working on a web application written with PHP and uses SQL Server 2008. To connect to database, I used SQLSRV driever of Microsoft. In a part of this application, I have to use SQL Transactions. As Microsoft suggested, I did it exactly based on this article. The main processes in my codes follow these steps:
1- starting sql transaction
2-  send information to PHP files through jQuery and check the result sent by JSON
3- rollback if the result was false and go to the next query if it was true.
4- commit transactions if no error occurred and all results were ok.

```
// This is my pseudo code
if (sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $sqlsrv->sqlsrvLink ) === true) {

  $firstQuery = sqlsrv_query($stmt1);
  if (!$firstQuery) {
     sqlsrv_rollback();
  } else {
     $nextQuery = sqlsrv_query($stmt2);
     if (!$nextQuery) {
        sqlsrv_rollback();
     } else {
        sqlsrv_commit();
     }
  }

} else {
   print_r(sqlsrv_errors()); // Here is where I get the error below.
}
```

The problem I have is this error:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server] New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

I'm using SQLSRV driver ver.2.
What is this error for? How can I solve it?

I included the my own sqlsrv class to the first part of index.php containing the methods below:

```
function __construct($dbServerName,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName)
{
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=> $dbName, "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
    $this->sqlsrvLink = sqlsrv_connect($dbServerName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($this->sqlsrvLink === false) {
        $this->sqlsrvError = sqlsrv_errors();
    }
}

function __destruct()
{
    sqlsrv_close($this->sqlsrvLink);
}
```

Comment: When is this error happening: before or after "sqlsrv_query($stmt1);"? Is it possible you have "sqlsrv_begin_transaction" somewhere before this pseudo-code?

Comment: @JScoobyCed: No, it must be in the current place. This is not a warning. It's an error. So it will stop all the processes. None of 2 queries won't execute.

Comment: I meant, do you have another call to "sqlsrv_begin_transaction" before this pseudo-code, therefore it would complaint that another transaction is already started. Did you try debugging the code so you can identify at which line of code the error happens.

Comment: Other SQL Transactions are not in this file, and they became committed or rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should set `MultipleActiveResultSets` to `true` when you want to connect to sql server :

```
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect('127.0.0.1', array
        (
           'Database' => 'Adventureworks',
           'MultipleActiveResultSets' => true, // MARS ENABLED
        ));
```

http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

Answer (score 0):

From your error, It seems like `$nextQuery = sqlsrv_query($stmt2);` is starting a new transaction in the same session. Can you commit `!$firstQuery` before starting the second?

Comment: Colin, so what is this Transaction for? Absolutely No. I have to commit the transaction if all parts of processes can gain success in their operations.